# How to write script for Line of sight and Viewshed analysis in Global Mapper

Tags: raster, viewshed, visibility, global-mapper

I wanted to write script in Global Mapper for Line of Sight and Viewshed analysis. I tried to calculate using Viewshed and Global Mapper Tools but the issue I am facing is that analysis is user specific, meaning we have to give observer point manually. Every time it is very difficult to give observer point.

I wanted to know whether there are any other methods to give multiple points or point to a .shp file as input point and DEM as input raster. I am very new to Global Mapper. I am reading about scripting in Global Mapper but I didn't understand how to use it. My thinking is to write script which will give multiple points as input (similar to batch processing) which will give me output of the viewshed of each points.

Is it possible? Does anyone know about it?

Comment: I think one cannot completely automate viewshed analysis completely rather you can give multiple points as input and select those point with digitizer tool and perform viewshed analysis.

Comment: thanks...its difficult task to edit thousands of address points manually.

Comment: you can do multiple at a time by selecting points for the transmitter location with the Digitizer Tool, then left clicking with the View Shed tool to calculate the sheds from multiple points.